# How to properly store an array of objects in a cookie using json.stringify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, stringify

I'm trying to store an array of objects in a cookie using JSON.Stringify but I'm having a problem when I parse the cookie and try to push a new object to the array to then stringify it again. It tells me that comments.push is not a function.

```js
var comments = [];
var myData = 0;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var commentAux = getCookie("myComments");
    if (commentAux != "") {
        //alert("Welcome again " + user);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function validateComment() {
 var x = document.forms["commentForm"]["commentSection"].value;
 if (x == null || x == "") {
  alert("There's nothing to comment, write something to proceed.");
  return false;
 } else {
  var comment = {
   firstName:"Name",
   lastName:"Surname",
   text:x
  };
  if (checkCookie() == false) {
   setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify(comment), 1);
  } else {
   myData = getCookie("myComments");
   comments = JSON.parse(myData);
   alert(comments);
   comments.push(comment);
   setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify(comments), 1);
  }
 }
 alert(comments.length);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Facebook Simulator by Azael Alanis</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="facebook-banner.png" alt="Facebook-Banner" style="height:100px;width:800px">
  <div id="section">
   <form name="commentForm" onsubmit="validateComment()">
    <input type="text" name="commentSection" placeholder="What's on your mind?"><button class="buttonText">Enviar</button>
   </form> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem?
I just want to parse my cookie -> add new object to array -> stringify it again

Thanks

Comment: Comments seems like an object, not an array.

Comment: There's a way to convert it to array?

Comment: If you are not using the cookie on the server, do not use a cookie...Use local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this code:

```
var comment = { /* ... */ };
if (checkCookie() == false) {
    setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify(comment), 1);
} else {
    comments = JSON.parse(getCookie("myComments"));
    comments.push(comment);
    setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify(comments), 1);
}
```

The problem is that initially you store the object `comment` instead of an array containing it.

Therefore, the next time, when you attempt to push another `comment`, you can't.

Try the following instead:

```
var comment = { /* ... */ };
if (checkCookie() == false) {
    setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify([comment]), 1); // <-- array
} else {
    comments = JSON.parse(getCookie("myComments"));
    comments.push(comment);
    setCookie("myComments", JSON.stringify(comments), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
comments = JSON.parse(myData);
comments.push(comment);
```

You probably meant to do

```
var comment = JSON.parse(myData);
comments.push(comment);
```

Since `JSON.parse(myData)` returns a comment object.